# How to do association rules from basket analysis in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to do create association rule with bigquery.
Where support is the number of occurrence of itemset/ total orders

Here's a sample dataset

| order_id | item | category | saleprice | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | colgate | toothpaste | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | kellogs | breakfast | 5 | 1 |
| 1 | dettol | antispetic | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | colgate | toothpaste | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | kellogs | breakfast | 5 | 3 |
| 3 | kellogs | breakfast | 5 | 1 |
| 3 | dettol | antispetic | 3 | 2 |

into association rules the desired result

| itemset_buy | itemset_support | consequent_items | consequent_support | support |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| colgate-kellogs-dettol | 0.3 | colgate-kellogs-dettol | 0.3 | 0.0 |
| colgate-kellogs-dettol | 0.3 | dettol-colgate | 0.3 | 0.0 |
| colgate-kellogs-dettol | 0.3 | dettol-kellogs | 0.3 | 0.0 |
| colgate-kellogs-dettol | 0.3 | colgate | 0.6 | 0 |
| colgate-kellogs-dettol | 0.3 | kellog | 0.6 | 0 |
| colgate-kellogs-dettol | 0.3 | dettol | 0.6 | 0 |
| colgate-kellogs | 0.3 | colgate-kellogs-dettol | 0.3 | 0.0 |
| colgate-kellogs | 0.3 | dettol-colgate | 0.3 | 0.0 |
| colgate-kellogs | 0.3 | dettol-kellogs | 0.3 | 0.0 |
| colgate-kellogs | 0.3 | colgate | 0.6 | 0 |
| colgate-kellogs | 0.3 | kellog | 0.6 | 0 |
| colgate-kellogs | 0.3 | dettol | 0.6 | 0 |
| colgate-dettol | 0.3 | colgate-kellogs-dettol | 0.3 | 0.0 |
| colgate-dettol | 0.3 | dettol-colgate | 0.3 | 0.0 |
| colgate-dettol | 0.3 | dettol-kellogs | 0.3 | 0.0 |
| colgate-dettol | 0.3 | colgate | 0.6 | 0 |
| colgate-dettol | 0.3 | kellog | 0.6 | 0 |
| colgate-dettol | 0.3 | dettol | 0.6 | 0 |
| colgate | 0.6 | colgate-kellogs-dettol | 0.3 | 0.0 |
| colgate | 0.6 | dettol-colgate | 0.3 | 0.0 |
| colgate | 0.6 | dettol-kellogs | 0.3 | 0.3 |
| colgate | 0.6 | colgate | 0.6 | 0 |
| colgate | 0.6 | kellog | 0.6 | 0.3 |
| colgate | 0.6 | dettol | 0.6 | 0.3 |
| dettol | 0.6 | dettol-colgate | 0.3 | 0.0 |
| dettol | 0.6 | dettol-kellogs | 0.3 | 0.0 |
| dettol | 0.6 | colgate | 0.6 | 0.3 |
| dettol | 0.6 | kellog | 0.6 | 0.3 |
| dettol | 0.6 | dettol | 0.6 | 0.3 |
| kellogs | 0.6 | dettol-colgate | 0.3 | 0.3 |
| kellogs | 0.6 | dettol-kellogs | 0.3 | 0.0 |
| kellogs | 0.6 | colgate | 0.6 | 0.3 |
| kellogs | 0.6 | kellog | 0.6 | 0.0 |
| kellogs | 0.6 | dettol | 0.6 | 0.3 |

right now I can only do the cross join for single items, how do I do a check for support in the association rules?

right now my code only gets the single items

```
itemsupport as (
select distinct 
item, count(distinct order_id)/count(distinct order_id) over() support 
from table_orderDetails 
)
select 
sa.item itemset_buy,sa.support itemset_support, 
itemsupport.itemset consequent_items, itemsupport.support consequent_support,
string_agg(struct(sa.itemset, itemsupport.item) helpersupport #helper to find support 
 from itemsupport sa
left join itemsupport using(item)
```

this gives me until the consequent_support. How do I check for support where for example for 1st cross join from row in association rules for itemset colgate-kellogs-dettol-colgate-kellogs-dettol is check in order details if it exist and if it does is divided by total orders?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the `expected (desired) results`.

Comment: hi for expected (desired) results is provided above. Basically it cross joins and checks the probability of string_aggr items is in item details